# Org-mode link to function definition

Tags: org-mode, functions, org-link

Is it possible to link to a function definition in a source code file, rather than a fixed line number?

Comment: Are you referring to external links like `file:mysource_file.c:555`? How should the link look like when jumping to a function `my_function()` in `mysource_file.c` instead of line 555 in that file? Note that the hook `org-open-at-point-functions` can be used to customize link behavior. Also new link types can be added using the `org-add-link-type` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [suggested global binding](http://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation) `C-c l` for storing a link when you are visiting *any* file (not just an org-mode file) and the one for inserting a link into an org file, `C-c C-l`, should work fine. It does not do the elisp `find-function` bit that John Kitchin describes in his answer, but it should be adequate for almost all situations. But you need `org-context-in-file-links` to be set to `t`: AFAICT that has been the default since 2008, but if you get line numbers instead of context in file links, check the setting of that variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already do this, but I'm looking for something more intelligent than a static line number to cope with when functions move around over time.

Comment: The links I get contain match patterns, not static line numbers. Try setting `org-context-in-file-links` to `t`.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the info about `org-context-in-file-links`.

Answer (score 9):

For elisp that is certainly possible. The general strategy might be something like:

```
[[elisp:(find-function 'describe-function)]]
```

You could add a description if you wanted to also, e.g.

```
[[elisp:(find-function 'describe-function)][describe-function]]
```

For other languages it wouldn't be that easy. You can make a link like this:

```
[[file:~/vc/projects/neural-network/aenet-1.0.0/src/aenet.f90::subroutine%20aenet_init(atom_types,%20stat)]]
```

which will open that file and search for the contents after the ::. Those contents are escaped.

Comment: Thanks, John. Is there anyway to capture the contents after::. when I capture the link. Perhaps by highlighting some text?

Comment: It looks like you can highlight some text in a file, and then type C-c l to store a link to that text. It is still search based. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is in fact possible to link directly to a help page, which should serve the purpose of linking to a function. Although it's not yet documented on https://orgmode.org/org.html#External-Links, the `help:` link type works, at least since 2016. For example, `[[help:org-link-parameters]]` links to the function where the `help:` link  (and many of the other built-in ones) are defined. Furthermore, running `org-store-link` (`C-c l`) on a Help page will store a link to the Help page.